# How to loop with random starting point?

Tags: javascript, html

To simplify my riddle:
There are 5 buttons. Each button will play a video when click.
When the video is finished, it will automatically play the next video. For instance, If I click the 3rd button, it will play the 3rd video, when it ends, it will continuously play the 4th video, and then 5th video......

Here is the question:
No matter which button I click. I want it to loop through all the videos. Once it has played all 5 videos. It will show the 6th video at the ending.
For example: If I click the 3rd button, it will play the 3rd, 4th, 5th video, and then loop back to 1st, 2nd video. Then play the 6th video.
Example2: If I click the 4th button, it will play the 4th, 5th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd video. Then the 6th video.

This greatly simplified my actual problem. Therefore, I can't show you the actual code. I have tried to create a loop  within 5 buttons.

Here is my logic: 
When I begin clicking any of those buttons, it will set  `var count = 0;`
and then when each video is finished, it does `count++;` if `count <= 4`, it will continuously loop, else it will play the 6th video.

I don't know if my logic is correct, maybe you can point me to a better way to do this. thankyou

Answer (score 2):

here is my logic way

```
//put variable to store the n-th button you click
var videoClick = button click;

//loop for 5
for(var counter=0; counter<5; counter++){
    //code to play your n-th video
    xxxxxxx
    //code to increment video order
    if(videoClick>=5){videoclick=1;}else{videoClick++;}
}

//code to play the 6th video here
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modulus operator:

```
function handleClickOnItemOfIndex(index) {
  const numOfItems = getNumberOfItems();
  if (numOfItems > 0) {
    for (var i=index; i<numOfItems + index; i++) {
      doSomethingWithItemOfIndex(i % numOfItems);
    }
  }
}
```